# My Full DNA: Whole Genome Sequencing with mtDNA from dante labs

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, 23andme, mitochondrial-dna, dante-labs

I have done 23andme. And I see there is a 23andme tag and an Ancestry.com tag.
I have just come across an ad from Dante Labs for "My Full DNA: Whole Genome Sequencing with mtDNA."

While I have a PhD in chemical engineering and a BSE in bioengineering, I do not have enough knowledge of modern genetic testing to know if this offer from Dante Labs is significantly better than what I already have from 23andme or not. Here is link https://us.dantelabs.com/collections/our-tests/products/whole-genome-sequencing-wgs-full-dna-analysis

Comment: This test is being sold as a health screening test. I can't speak to its utility for that, and this is probably not the right site to discuss genetic health screening. But if Dante Labs aren't offering any matching algorithm and user/tree database, then there's unlikely to be much immediate benefit for genealogical studies. Possibly one day Gedmatch or others will import full-genome data for comparisons, at which point it could make more sense.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between a DNA test for genealogy and a WGS (Whole Genome Sequencing) test is that the test for genealogy obtains values for about 700,000 SNPs (Single Nuleotide Polymorphisms), whereas the WGS obtains the values for all 3 billion positions in your genome. For genealogy purposes, the 700,000 are enough, because they are picked from among the 10 million or so SNPs, which are positions where the values in humans vary. Those 700,000 SNPs are compared against the same SNPs in other people to see to whom you match and whom you don't. Trying to compare 3 billion positions, where most are the same just adds extra processing with no significant improvement for matching people. So for genealogical purposes, there is no reason to get a WGS test.

Health issues are a different matter. If what you are really looking for is personal health information from your DNA (which I gather from your handle: SEID Sufferer), then you were right to go first with 23andMe. Among the 700,000 or so SNPs they test are ones they specially pick for health purposes. Their reports may provide some information on the ailments that might be of interest to you. You can then download the raw data from 23andMe and upload that to [Promethease](https://www.promethease.com/) which for a small fee of $10 to $20, will provide you with additional health information and possibly include the ailments you are interested in.

I did a WGS with Dante labs last fall. What they do that's different is that they will do the WGS test and provide you with health reports on [ailments that you request information on](https://us.dantelabs.com/blogs/news/how-dante-labs-can-help-you-get-your-diagnosis). The reports they provide on each ailment is very technical (so much so, that I couldn't interpret mine, other than my DNA was negative for one and positive for the other of the two minor issues that I had requested). During Rare Disease Month (Feb 2019), they are offering [several detailed additional reports](https://us.dantelabs.com/pages/rare-disease-month-faq). These reports contain much more than the 23andMe health information, and are better organized than the Promethease information. If you are interested in your genetic health, or in a specific ailment, and have the ability to interpret it correctly, then Dante's test likely will be worth the cost of the test to you.

Answer (score 2):

Each genealogical testing company selects a proprietary portion of the approximately 700,000 SNPs to include in their test and this changes over time with different versions of their test as they evolve:

- 23andMe

  - v3 11/2010 to 11/2013
  - v4 11/2013 to 08/2017
  - v5 08/2017 to at least 01/2020
  - according to their API since 11/2007
- Ancestry

  - v1 01/2012 to 05/2016
  - v2 05/2016 to at least 01/2020
- Family Tree DNA

  - v2 02/2011 to 04/2019
  - v3 04/2019 to at least 01/2020
- Living DNA

  - v1 09/2016 to 10/2018
  - v2 10/2018 to at least 01/2020
- MyHeritage

  - v1 11/2016 to 03/2019
  - v2 03/2019 to at least 01/2020

Therefore, as you compare to cousins that are farther away, if they tested on a different company, their matching may not come up above a 7 cM threshold.  For example, if you tested on Ancestry and your cousin on Family Tree DNA and your actual match is 7.1 cM the match found across companies might only be 6.8 cM for example, and thus you might not see them.

By doing WGS (Whole Genome Sequencing), you are testing everything (many billions of SNPs) and you can create a super kit (e.g., GEDmatch tier1 tools) that includes the selected SNPs from every testing company and every version and thus potentially get an accurate comparison against kits of any company on GEDmatch.

For me, doing genealogical research, it is worth it and I have retested many of my cousins.  Over thanksgiving they had the 30x WGS on sale for $200.  The list price of $600 would not be worth it to me.  Note that this is advanced stuff, so you need to be pretty computer savy to handle the results and follow the instructions.  Dante Labs does not do it for you, you must bring in 3rd party open-source tools to your computer and process the data yourself or go to third party sites for help. Dante 30x WGS also includes mtDNA and yDNA which would need to go to yFull.com for haplogroup analysis.  (The 30x means they test each position 30 times for high accuracy.)